# How to convert date value in a facelet?

Tags: date, jsf, jsf-2, converters

I have the `rich:calendar` element in a facelet:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{listBean.to}"
                popup="true"
                datePattern="d/M/yy"
                cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px"/>
```

where listBean's defined as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ListBean {

    private Date to;
    //GET, SET, Others
}
```

and I need to convert the date, picked up by user to the end of a day date. I can convert it in Java as follows:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
to = date.getTime();
```

But I would not like to write those lines of code and would like to move this convertion in the facelet. Is it possible?

Comment: This is business logic and does not belong in the facelet imo

Comment: I'm not familiar with internal working of `<rich:calendar>` (e.g. what value types does it support, and does it perform an implicit conversion based on date pattern, etc), but as to performing conversion in JSF in general, you normally use a normal converter for that. E.g. `<f:convertDateTime>` or a custom `Converter` implementation. Have you ever considered or even tried that?